# Facebook 'About Me' and requesting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I am successfully getting some info from FB, like Likes, and Friends, but I cannot figure out what is the 'code' for 'About Me'?

Here is my code for Fb Likes and Friends:

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/' + authData.facebook.id + '/friends?access_token=' + authData.facebook.accessToken +'', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var fbFriends = data;
      });
      $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/' + authData.facebook.id + '/likes?access_token=' + authData.facebook.accessToken +'', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var fbLikes = data;

      });
```

So, what should I put instead of "/friends?" or "/likes?" to get About Me? Btw, is there any list of those things?

Thanks,
uksz

EDIT:

I permission that I ask user  for are the following:  user_friends,user_about_me,user_likes,public_profile,publish_actions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, I managed to work-around to this problem by simply:

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/' + authData.facebook.id + '/?access_token=' + authData.facebook.accessToken +'', function (data) {

    var about = data.bio;

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the official Facebook docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Try /me?fields=friends,likes,about

Comment: Yeah, I've tried 'me', but I get an error: 
 "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /me",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }

Comment: You need to supply an User Access Token.